# using spring test context to initialize data

Tags: spring, spring-test

I was wondering if it's possible to initialize test data by implementing the TestExecutionListener interface and use the beforeTestClass and afterTestClass to load/dispose data. The test data will be available in a flat file and I would like the data file location to be as part of the test class annotation

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:spring/test-dao.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners(
{ 
  DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
  InsertTestDataExecutionListener.class
})
@DataSetLocation("classpath:data/test-dao-dataset.xml")
public abstract class AbstractDaoTests {
   public List testdata....
}
```

In the above pseudocode, the InsertTestDataExecutionListener will implement the TestExecutionListener interface and in the beforeClass method, get the dataset location from the annotation. I am trying to find out how I could setup the contents of the property 'testdata' using the TestContext.

```
public class InsertTestDataExecutionListener implements TestExecutionListener {
   public void beforeTestClass(TestContext aContext) {
       DataSetLocation dsLocation = aContext.getTestClass().getAnnotation(
            DataSetLocation.class
            );
       //Load the contents of the file using the dataset location.

       ?? How to set the property of 'testdata' from the Abstract class
   }
}
```

Should I be using reflection to do the work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I undestand it is not required to access Spring context during data load (it is just plain file in classpath). So, you may do the work without listeners:

```
public abstract class AbstractDaoTests {
   public List testdata;
   public List getTestData() {...}
   public abstract String getDataLocation();

   public AbstractDaoTests () {
       testData = loadDataFromLocation(getTestData());
   }
}


public class ConcreteTest extend AbstractDaoTests  {
    @Override
    public String getDataLocation() {return "classpath:data/test-dao-dataset.xml";}
}
```

Of course you may use annotation instead of abstract method and get it from `this.getClass().getAnnotation` in constuctor.